# What are the interfaces implemented in the object passed to hook_query_alter()?

Tags: hooks, database

Looking at the documentation for [hook_query_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_query_alter/7), I see that the parameter is reported to implement [QueryAlterableInterface](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--query.inc/interface/QueryAlterableInterface/7); looking at the code of [_node_query_node_access_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/_node_query_node_access_alter/7), called by an implementation of `hook_query_TAG_alter()`, I notice that it is using methods not defined in the `QueryAlterableInterface` interface, such as `$query->getTables()`.

If I implement `hook_query_alter()`, or `hook_query_TAG_alter()`, what methods should I use, and which methods can I effectively use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In core, the `QueryAlterableInterface` interface is extended by the [`SelectQueryInterface`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--select.inc/interface/SelectQueryInterface/7) interface, which is where you'll find [`SelectQueryInterface::getTables()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--select.inc/function/SelectQueryInterface%3A%3AgetTables/7).

[`SelectQuery`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--select.inc/class/SelectQuery/7) and [`SelectQueryExtender`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--select.inc/class/SelectQueryExtender/7), in turn, implement `SelectQueryInterface` and, by extension, `QueryAlterableInterface`.

Comment: I guess that the argument for that hook should be defined as `SelectQueryInterface $query`, then; the current definition would imply that you cannot count on methods implemented in `SelectQueryInterface`.